# Is there any way to get mysqli_error without CONNECTION variable?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As far as I know, the only way to get mysqli error info is:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
///RUN QUERY HERE, and if error:
$error=mysqli_error($con);
```

However (thinking I was smart) my whole software is programmed with a function that gets con info, as there are multiple databases and tables. So my queries look more like this.

```
$query=mysqli_query(CON("USER_DATABASE"),"INSERT INTO users (column) VALUES ("VALUE") ");
run_query($query); ///In this function I either run the query,
```

or record a failed query. However cannot record the specific error.

Is there any way at all to somehow still capture a mysqli_error(); without having the $con in the mysqli_error() function? Perhaps with the $query variable?

Comment: Yes, another - the proper - method is to apply exception handling for mysqli. Read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors). The second link presents the theorie regarding PDO, but it actually applies to mysqli too.

Comment: BTW I don't understand this run query thing.  With mysqli_query you are **already** running a query. "Running" it again makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as there are multiple databases and tables.

The number of tables doesn't matter.

As if the databases, your application should have one connection variable per database(however, I would rather say that you are doing something wrong if you need *multiple* databases in a simple application).

Either way, there is a way to get Mysqli error without a connection variable. To make it possible , you should tell Mysqli to start throwing exceptions. Just add this line

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

So the simplest solution for you would be to make con() function *static* and return the same connection instance every time it is called.

But you should reconsider the architecture, and make it better organized, using just one database unless it's absolutely necessary and also use OOP to get rid of static functions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hmm okay so this is in the right direction. However, now I am getting the error output as "Fatal ERROR: Details here" and the page dies as expected. Is there any way to place those error details in a variable so I can save them? The reason why is because, even though some queries may fail I don't want to output an error code and kill the page because they aren't necessarily "critical". Basically my run_query($query); function does if(!$query) { SEND ALERT TO ADMIN} so we know something happened. However, because the $con variable doesn't exist, we can't get the error.

Comment: Well, actually you don't need a variable. Everything you need already exists in PHP, you just have to configure it according yo your needs. I wrote an article explaining these matters, [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) which I encourage you to read and get back if you will have any question regarding particular implementation. By the way, what is proposed traffic for the site/service?

Comment: Thank you for the info! I know of error_logs, however I am hoping I can forward all error_logs to one log instead of a new one in each directory. The reason I was trying to place mysqli_error in a varibale was so I could email it to myself. Will check out your article. Thanks! I am an entrepreneur and as you can tell, amateur coder. I have built a successful "company portal" software for franchises which is supported by a few other softwares we own that integrate with it. All kept on the same server but largely different applications which is why there are different databases.

Comment: error logs are going in different directories only if you use a *relative* file name. But as long as the filename is *absolute*, they all go into the same file. I've got an article in this issue as well: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Answer (score 2):

> However (thinking I was smart) my whole software is programmed with a function that gets con info, as there are multiple databases and tables. So my queries look more like this.

Don't do that. Not only does it make it more difficult to retrieve error information, but -- more importantly! -- it means that your application will make a completely new database connection for every query. This will make your application *significantly* slower.

If your application really needs to connect to multiple databases, consider passing a symbolic name for the database as a parameter, and caching connections to all databases that have been used in a static variable.